# insert into existing sqlite database android

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

when try insert new data in database send this error : "attached database stopped" and app isclosed !

this database class and insert method:

```
public boolean insertUser(String userName, int age, int gender, int password, String memDescription, String pic) {  
    User user = null;  
    openDatabase();  
    db.beginTransaction();  
    try {  
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
        values.put("userName", user.getUserName());  
        values.put("age", user.getAge());  
        values.put("gender", user.getGender());  
        values.put("password", user.getPassword());  
        values.put("memDescription", user.getMemDescription());  
        values.put("pic", user.getPic());  
        long result = db.insertOrThrow("tblUsers", null, values);  
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();  
        closeDatabase();  
        if (result == -1)  
            return false;  
        else  
            return true;  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
        Log.d(TAG, "???? ??? ?? ???????");  
        return false;  
    } finally {  
        db.endTransaction();  
        closeDatabase();  
    }  
}
```

and this code in insert activity :

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);  
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View view) {  
            try {  
                boolean isInserted = DB_HELPER.insertUser(EDT_NAME.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(EDT_AGE.getText().toString()),  
                        Integer.parseInt(EDT_GENDER.getText().toString()), Integer.parseInt(EDT_PASS.getText().toString()),  
                        EDT_DESC.getText().toString(), EDT_PIC.getText().toString());  
                if (isInserted == true)  
                    startActivity(new Intent(AddActivity.this, MainActivity.class));  
                else  
                    Snackbar.make(view, "??? ?? ??? ????? ????!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();  
            } catch(Exception e){  
                e.printStackTrace();  
                return;  
            }  
        }  
    });
```

and this user table class :

```
public class User {  
private int id;  
private String userName;  
private int age;  
private int gender;  
private int password;  
private String memDescription;  
private String pic;  

public User(int id, String userName, int age, int gender, int password, String memDescription, String pic) {  
    this.id = id;  
    this.userName = userName;  
    this.age = age;  
    this.gender = gender;  
    this.password = password;  
    this.memDescription = memDescription;  
    this.pic = pic;  
}  

public int getId() {  
    return id;  
}  

public void setId(int id) {  
    this.id = id;  
}  

public String getUserName() {  
    return userName;  
}  

public void setUserName(String userName) {  
    this.userName = userName;  
}  

public int getAge() {  
    return age;  
}  

public void setAge(int age) {  
    this.age = age;  
}  

public int getGender() {  
    return gender;  
}  

public void setGender(int gender) {  
    this.gender = gender;  
}  

public int getPassword() {  
    return password;  
}  

public void setPassword(int password) {  
    this.password = password;  
}  

public String getMemDescription() {  
    return memDescription;  
}  

public void setMemDescription(String memDescription) {  
    this.memDescription = memDescription;  
}  

public String getPic() {  
    return pic;  
}  

public void setPic(String pic) {  
    this.pic = pic;  
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you initialize user variable? As i see it's null.

Comment: Remove closeDatabase() below  db.setTransactionSuccessful();  because you have already close in finally method. finally method always call

Comment: now insert into database is OK when Remove closeDatabase() below db.setTransactionSuccessful(); .... thank's Dear Mavya Soni